# Set the major mode of a new buffer interactively

Tags: buffers, major-mode

When creating a new buffer via:

1. `C-x b`
2. `NonExistentBufferName` `RET` `RET`

I would like Emacs to ask me what major mode this buffer is going to use upon opening.
Moreover, I want Emacs to infer the major mode in some cases based on the buffer's name:

1. `C-x b`
2. `test.org`(no such buffer so far) `RET` `RET`
   => org-mode is used without asking me anything.

Could anybody advice if I can use any package for this? Or is it achievable at all via pure elisp?

P.S.
I'm using `ido` if it matters.

Comment: I've migrated this over to emacs.SE. Flag for merger with your other question. Please don't cross post the next time.

Answer (score 2):

Add entries in the `magic-mode-alist`/`auto-mode-alist` (in your init file most likely) if you want emacs to automatically determine major mode from buffer/file names (<kbd>C-h v</kbd> `auto-mode-alist` for info).

To interactively set the major mode just use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `<mode-name, eg. c-mode>`.

If you actually want emacs to interactively prompt you for a major mode every time you open a buffer, that could be achieved via a small advice to function you use to visit files (the ido functions in your case).

Comment: `auto-mode-alist` seems to be working only with file buffers. Yeah, I'm looking for a way to have Emacs prompt me for a major mode. I tried to find the right function to hook it up

Comment: @DmitrySenin yea that is for file buffers, perhaps `magic-mode-alist` would meet your needs.  Otherwise, you could write a small function for completing read of available modes and advise the finding function

Comment: @Rorschach I am trying to have emacs prompt me for one of two modes for a specific file extension, and `magic-mode-alist` seems to be what I am after. How would the assigned function have to be? Thanks in advance.